# Controller Show Action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models Users(devise gem) and Profiles where

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile

  class Profile < AciveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
```

Everything in the views of each model works fine, but I want to have a link_to in the application layout.

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to current_user.username , profile_path(@profile) %></li>
```

But it shows me this error:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"})
```

My profile controller

```
  def show 
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @profile }
end
```

end

My rake routes:

```
            profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                             profiles#index
                     POST   /profiles(.:format)                             profiles#create
         new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                         profiles#new
        edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                    profiles#edit
             profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                         profiles#show
                     PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                         profiles#update
                     DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                         profiles#destroy
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                       devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#update

 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                    registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                           registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                   registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      registrations#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                           registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                           registrations#destroy
```

I want that the link displays the currentuser.username ( I have Devise Username already) and link to the profile page of the current_user.

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste `params`? try removing `@profile` from `profile_path(@profile)`

Comment: Getting the same error, sorry but which `params` did you mean?

Comment: `params` hash which has all the parameters you send though url in this case `@profile`. You should send `@profile.id` and also check whether controller is named `Profile` or `Profiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting `@profile` in the actions that actually use the layout, so it's coming up as nil, and the router needs an id to generate the route.

You need to be setting @profile to something in any action that renders with the application layout. This is possibly a job for a global before_filter.